# Converting Multilingual FastText Vectors to Spacy Model

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a multilingual FastText Vector (Indonesia, Malay, and English. in one file vector). I want to converting into spacy model using
python -m init-model ... vectors-loc [filename vectors].

What init-model should I use?

or Any other way to extract the vector?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Show us the code you have made so far.

Comment: @JeroenHeier Im working in terminal. And use same way like this:
'python -m spacy init-model en /tmp/la_vectors_wiki_lg --vectors-loc cc.la.300.vec.gz'.

https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity